# Defining three.js in current project structure not working

Tags: javascript, module, three.js, requirejs

Trying to get started with Three.js. Cannot get my project running locally. I am trying to use require to load three.js in my main script.

Here is the code at the top of my main.js:

```
var THREE= {
    REVISION: "79"
};

if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd) {
    define("three", THREE)
}

else if("undefined"!==typeof exports&&"undefined"!==typeof module) {
    module.exports=THREE
}
```

I have version 79 of three.js in my scripts folder

```
  index.html 
  scripts/
    main.js
    require.js
    three/
      three.min.js
```

However I still get the error in my HTML where I call `var obj = new THREE.Object3D();`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

I am not strong with require. So I am not sure where the require.config is. I downloaded require and here is the code where I think I am supposed to edit:

```
  function newContext(contextName) {
    var inCheckLoaded, Module, context, handlers,
        checkLoadedTimeoutId,
        config = {
            //Defaults. Do not set a default for map
            //config to speed up normalize(), which
            //will run faster if there is no default.
            waitSeconds: 7,
            baseUrl: '',
            paths: {
             "three": "../three/three.min.js"
            },
            bundles: {},
            pkgs: {},
            shim: {
                three: {
                    exports: 'THREE'
                }
            },
            config: {}
        },
        registry = {},
        //registry of just enabled modules, to speed
        //cycle breaking code when lots of modules
        //are registered, but not activated.
        enabledRegistry = {},
        undefEvents = {},
        defQueue = [],
        defined = {},
        urlFetched = {},
        bundlesMap = {},
        requireCounter = 1,
        unnormalizedCounter = 1;
```

Comment: What is the context of `var obj = new THREE.Object3D()`?  Where is that coming from?

Comment: @MichaelSacket thats my problem I have the files in my project directory I am confused on how to make three.js visible to the html file. where i am using the obj. the error i am getting is Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE  is not defined.